# Bug with user list's reputations

Tags: support

If you click on "Users" on the navigation bar of the main Seasoned Advice, it will take you to a list of all the users. You can then choose to sort the users with different categories. If you sort by reputation and choose week, it will display the reputation correctly like this:

[image]

But then if you go and sort by reputation and month, the reputation shown is less than the week's reputation, which obviously is incorrect. Just look at FuzzyChef's week rep(234) and then his month rep(60):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Week" refers to the start of the week. Today being Saturday, February 4th, that would be Sunday, January 29th.

"Month" means since the beginning of the calendar month. That's Wednesday, February 1st.

The "week" rep is higher than the "month" rep because more days have gone by during this week than during this calendar month.

This happens every month, unless the month happens to start on a Sunday. You'll even see it happening with the "quarter" and "year" rep during the first few days of the quarter and year, respectively.

This is a normal function of calendar-based reporting. We can certainly question the merits of "to date" reporting on smaller sites (and many of us *did* question them, myself included), but as long as that's the design, this isn't a bug.

Comment: Haha sometimes logic escapes me. Thanks!